# sort column 2 by interval and sort column 1 desc

Tags: mysql, range, between

I need a SQL statement where it first sorts by a interval of 1000 `Hours` steps and after that sorts the `Points` in DESC order.
I cant figure out how to use `Case` or `Between`/`case` in this example.

current result with
`SELECT * FROM  CurrencyUser ORDER BY Hours DESC, Points DESC LIMIT 6`

```
+--------+-------+
| Points | Hours |
+--------+-------+
|    27  |  8005 |
|    125 |  7200 |
|    200 |  7100 |
|    567 |  1070 |
|    575 |  1050 |
|    450 |  1020 |
+--------+-------+
```

and this is my wanted result

```
+--------+-------+
| Points | Hours |
+--------+-------+
|    27  |  8005 |
|    200 |  7100 |
|    125 |  7200 |
|    575 |  1050 |
|    567 |  1070 |
|    450 |  1020 |
+--------+-------+
```

both Points and Hours are normal integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM  CurrencyUser ORDER BY cast(Hours/1000 as int) DESC, Points DESC LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: it worked with 
`SELECT * FROM CurrencyUser ORDER BY cast(Hours/1000 as SIGNED) DESC, Points DESC LIMIT 6`
Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

Use either `FLOOR(Hours / 1000)` or `Hours DIV 1000`

```
SELECT *
FROM  CurrencyUser
ORDER BY Hours DIV 1000 DESC, Points DESC
```

Note that casting to `UNSIGNED` will act as `ROUND()` and thus `7400` will be in the group `7` but `7600` in the group `8`. This case is not covered by your sample data.

Run this test to see the difference:

```
set @Hours = 7600;

select cast(@Hours/1000 as unsigned)
     , round(@Hours/1000)
     , floor(@Hours/1000)
     , @Hours DIV 1000
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/DZYZ80148